# How to convert an HTML form value into an int in Golang

Tags: html, go, forms, typeconverter, strconv

My test Handler code is here:

```
func defineHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    a := strconv.ParseInt(r.FormValue("aRows")[0:], 10, 64);
    b := r.FormValue("aRows");
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "aRows is: %s", b);
}
```

The error returned during the compile comes out as:
"multiple-value strconv.ParseInt() in single-value context"

I believe it has to do with the format of information in the FormValue I just don't know how to alleviate that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that [`strconv.ParseInt`](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt) has multiple return values (the int, and an error), so you need to do:

```
a, err := strconv.ParseInt(r.FormValue("aRows")[0:], 10, 64);
if err != nil {
  // handle the error in some way
}
```

Comment: Not so embarassing. They *could* have designed the language so that your original code is correct. The `parseInt` in many languages is like that: If there's an error it throws an exception or returns `NaN` or something. Go is designed this way to urge you to think about errors and handle them. It takes some getting used to.